# PyQt5 Layout error (wrong Horizontal policy in QLabel: label)

Tags: python, user-interface, layout, pyqt5

**File: import.py**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file '/home/chris/Documents/papinhio-player/ui/menu-1/playlists/import/import-playlist.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.4
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(1786, 355)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/rest-windows/assets/images/rest-windows/import.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        Dialog.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Dialog)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(Dialog)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1784, 353))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("QLabel{\n"
"    font-weight:bold;\n"
"    color:green;\n"
"}")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.title = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.title.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.title.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.title.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.title.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.title.setObjectName("title")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.title, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.playlists_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.playlists_frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.playlists_frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.playlists_frame.setObjectName("playlists_frame")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.playlists_frame)
        self.gridLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.playlists_frame, 2, 0, 1, 2)
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("QFrame{border:none;}")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(7)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.save = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.save.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.save.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.save.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/rest-windows/assets/images/rest-windows/save.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.save.setIcon(icon1)
        self.save.setObjectName("save")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.save)
        self.cancel = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.cancel.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.cancel.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.cancel.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        self.cancel.setObjectName("cancel")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.cancel)
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame, 3, 0, 1, 2)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
        Dialog.setTabOrder(self.scrollArea, self.title)
        Dialog.setTabOrder(self.title, self.save)
        Dialog.setTabOrder(self.save, self.cancel)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Εισαγωγή λίστας αναπαραγωγής"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Σημείωση: Από την λίστα αναπαραγωγής εξήχθησαν τα αρχεία ήχου τα οποία βρέθηκαν ότι υπάρχουν, οι αναμεταδόσεις, καθώς και \"φωλιασμένες\" λίστες αναπαραγωγής."))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Τίτλος λίστας αναπαραγωγής:"))
        self.title.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Dialog", "Πληκτρλογήστε εδώ τον τίτλο της λίστας αναπαραγωγής"))
        self.save.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Αποθήκευση"))
        self.cancel.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Ακύρωση"))
import sys
sys.path.append('../../../')

import importlib
#icons = importlib.import_module('compiled-ui.icons')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

[image: Output result]

As you can see the `QLabel` with title `label`, has not the appropriate width.

How can i fix this?

The full text of label is: `Σημείωση: Από την λίστα αναπαραγωγής εξήχθησαν τα αρχεία ήχου τα οποία βρέθηκαν ότι υπάρχουν, οι αναμεταδόσεις, καθώς και \"φωλιασμένες\" λίστες αναπαραγωγής.` but it's not displayed in the screen.

**Edit:**

In Qt5 Designer the output is correct as expected, but when i run the pyuic5 compiled ui file the output is wrong.

Computer info: `Linux chris-Inspiron-3847 5.4.0-109-generic #123-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 8 09:10:54 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

[image]

Here is the ui file which is produced by Qt5 Designer:

**File: import-playlist.ui**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>715</width>
    <height>128</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Εισαγωγή λίστας αναπαραγωγής</string>
  </property>
  <property name="windowIcon">
   <iconset resource="../../../icons.qrc">
    <normaloff>:/main-window/assets/images/main-window/import-sound-file.png</normaloff>:/main-window/assets/images/main-window/import-sound-file.png</iconset>
  </property>
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
   <property name="leftMargin">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <property name="topMargin">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <property name="rightMargin">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <property name="bottomMargin">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <item row="0" column="0">
    <widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollArea">
     <property name="sizePolicy">
      <sizepolicy hsizetype="Ignored" vsizetype="Expanding">
       <horstretch>0</horstretch>
       <verstretch>0</verstretch>
      </sizepolicy>
     </property>
     <property name="widgetResizable">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <width>713</width>
        <height>126</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Ignored" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
       <item row="1" column="1">
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="title">
         <property name="placeholderText">
          <string>Πληκτρλογήστε εδώ τον τίτλο της λίστας αναπαραγωγής</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="2" column="0" colspan="2">
        <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Fixed">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">QFrame{border:none;}</string>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShape">
          <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShadow">
          <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
         </property>
         <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
          <property name="leftMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="topMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="rightMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="bottomMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <item>
           <widget class="QPushButton" name="save">
            <property name="sizePolicy">
             <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Fixed">
              <horstretch>0</horstretch>
              <verstretch>0</verstretch>
             </sizepolicy>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>Αποθήκευση</string>
            </property>
            <property name="icon">
             <iconset resource="../../../icons.qrc">
              <normaloff>:/rest-windows/assets/images/rest-windows/save.png</normaloff>:/rest-windows/assets/images/rest-windows/save.png</iconset>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QPushButton" name="cancel">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Ακύρωση</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="0" colspan="2">
        <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Preferred">
           <horstretch>1</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">QLabel{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:green;
}</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Σημείωση: Από την λίστα αναπαραγωγής εξήχθησαν τα αρχεία ήχου τα οποία βρέθηκαν ότι υπάρχουν, οι αναμεταδόσεις, καθώς και &quot;φωλιασμένες&quot; λίστες αναπαραγωγής.</string>
         </property>
         <property name="wordWrap">
          <bool>true</bool>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="0">
        <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Τίτλος λίστας αναπαραγωγής:</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <tabstops>
  <tabstop>scrollArea</tabstop>
  <tabstop>title</tabstop>
  <tabstop>save</tabstop>
  <tabstop>cancel</tabstop>
 </tabstops>
 <resources>
  <include location="../../../icons.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Set the `wordWrap` property for that label in Designer, and remember about [layout issues](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#layout-issues).

Comment: @musicamante it's setted to checked (True), that's my first thought about.

Comment: There's no trace of that property in your pyuic file.

Comment: Hm, interesting, maybe the Qt Designer doesn't set this property (maybe default value). I will try to manually change this and post the results.

Comment: Designer sets it and pyuic reads it correctly: I just tested it with a .ui file and I can see the `setWordWrap(True)` in the output code; there should be no reason for Designer or [py]uic to ignore that property, as it works using the QMetaObject features. Ensure that you've properly updated the pyuic file and you're actually using it. If you're ***completely*** sure about your ui file, then share *that* file.

Comment: @musicamante I updated the question with the ui file. There there is a word wrap property...

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Please provide the correct versions of OS, Qt and PyQt you're using.

Comment: It's strange: if i compile the file with `pyuic5 -x import-playlist.ui -o import-playlist.py` command works but if i run: `process = subprocess.Popen(["python3.9","-m","PyQt5.uic.pyuic","-x",original_path,"-o",saved_path], shell=False)` doesn't fix the setWordWrap error. (the property is setted but doesn't displayed correct)

Comment: Great now works! Thanks @musicamante
It was an old file (import.py instead of import-playlist.py), now it work as expected.

Comment: Good. Then, since it's not reproducible, I'd suggest you to remove this question. (Btw, both past forms of "to set" are the same as the infinite, so, it's always "set", there is no "setted"; see https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/163953)